# How to live-decrypt WPA/WPA2-PSK using tcpdump?

Tags: security, encryption, wifi, tcpdump

Here my Problem:

If I am connected to a network (so I know the WPA/WPA2-PSK), I´d like to be able to decrypt the traffic I capture from other devices in the network. 
(If WEP is used, tcpdump does this automatically).

As far as I know, WPA uses something like a session key for each client in the WiFi - but I know this is possible - so I´m wondering HOW to do this. (If this is not possibile with tcpdump, how to do this "by hand"?)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

I've written a small, open source, [application](https://github.com/mfontanini/dot11decrypt) that does exactly this.

Comment: I used the app written by mfontanini and after a couple of minor compilation hiccups (had to figure out the dependencies a bit) it worked great on my ARM Ubuntu 14.04 system. You do have to remember that you need to disconnect and re-associate any device you want to dump 'cause the pgm needs to see the 4-way handshake to be able to decrypt.

Answer (score 4):

If you capture the traffic with tcpdump and can save it to file you should be able to use Wireshark to decrypt it on a PC/Mac. You need to catch the association traffic and the four-way handshake and configure Wireshark with the PSK.

Comment: You can use TShark instead of Wireshark and do a live capturing. TShark is bundled with Wireshark.

Comment: Wireshark also allows you to run a remote live capture.

Answer (score 0):

TamoSoft has [CommView for WiFi](http://www.tamos.com/products/commwifi/) product which does what you need. As far as I know, decrypting WPA is a tricky task, and this is what they charge for.

Comment: The problem is, I´m trying to do this on Android - so I´ll have to do something myself... Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user727035 afaik Commview *cracks* passcodes for WPA, i.e. they perform cryptographic analysis on-the-fly. And they know some tricks and weak places. So I doubt that this is easily doable.